# Overriding Size of Element in Superview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I have a scrollview in my superclass, I want to override its size in one of the subclass views of this superclass.

I am using the following Init but my syntax for selecting the scrollview in the parent is wrong and throwing an error, where am i going wrong here?

The scrollView is in the parent view and i want to resize its frame thats set in the super

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    [super scrollView]; CGRectMake(50, 0, self.width - 50, self.height);
        [self setControlArray:[NSMutableArray new]];
        [self setBusOffset:1];
        [self addBusToView];
        [self addBusNavigationToView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Error is

> Property 'frame' cannot be found in forward class object 'CDCChannelScrollView'

I assume .frame isnt the correct accessor to edit the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer was to use setFrame:

```
[self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, self.width - 170, self.height)];
```